# I want to check whether a job with specified name is running in powershell, if so remove the job using Remove-Job

Tags: powershell-2.0

```
$abc={script}

Start-Job $abc -name MyTask
```

The script runs in the background for a long time and hence I want to remove it when it's still running. when I try to remove the job using `Remove-job -name MyTask -force`, it throws an error if the job was already removed. So I need an

```
If(Check the job name exist)
 {
     Remove-job -name MyTask -force 
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
if ( [bool](get-job -Name MyTask -ea silentlycontinue) )
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: -ea is short for -ErrorAction. Somtimes it just makes the code clearer to use the full names instead of abbrevations